# Shadow is not displaying on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, shadow

I have one ViewController and in that controller there are two UIViews.

I want to add at the bottom of first UIView shadow which is shown on this second UIView.

```
first UIView

-------------
              <- shadow here
secondUIView
```

But when I simply add this code it's not working.

```
 firstView.layer.masksToBounds = true
 firstView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,5)
 firstView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
 firstView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: firstView.bounds).CGPath
```

Comment: Check `shadowOpacity`, it defaults to 0

Answer (score 37):

If you set `maskToBounds` to `false`, it should show the shadow.

```
firstView.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

If the `masksToBounds` property is `true`, then anything that is outside the boundaries of the view will be clipped to those boundaries.

Comment: @ThirdMartian Well... I don't know... Could be something else then... I run your code exactly as you posted. I only changed `true` to `false` and made shadow offset `CGSizeMake(0, 25)` so I could clearly see the shadow. It worked.

Comment: I had to change order in storyboard, anyways, thank you for help !

Comment: @ThirdMartian this is most likely too late, but for those in the future, `firstView.clipsToBounds = false` would be necessary as well, just in case that was set to `true` earlier.

Answer (score 16):

If you have two views `view1` and `view2` and `view2` is just below `view1` it might be that `view2` covers shadow of `view1`. This happens when `view2` is added as subview after `view1`.

Add `view1` as subview after adding `view2` or call `[superview bringSubviewToFront:view1]` at some point.

Comment: Such a simple problem and so obvious once I read this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension UIView {
    
    public func addShadowToView(shadow_color: UIColor,offset: CGSize,shadow_radius: CGFloat,shadow_opacity: Float,corner_radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.shadowColor = shadow_color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadow_opacity
        self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadow_radius
        self.layer.cornerRadius = corner_radius
    }
}
```

Call that function as:

```
firstView.addShadowToView(shadow_color: UIColor.black, offset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 5), shadow_radius: 5.0, shadow_opacity: 0.5, corner_radius: 0.0)
```

Also make sure that your:

- view `clipsToBounds` property is false

  ```
  firstView.clipsToBounds = false
  ```
- firstView `backgroundColor` should not be clear color

  ```
  firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `firstView.layer.masksToBounds = true` as it will cause your view to clip the shadow off since it is technically out of its bounds.

Also if all you want is a normal shadow following your views shape you can remove `firstView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: firstView.bounds).CGPath` as well

Answer (score 0):

`masksToBounds = true`, it causes your shadow hidden.
One way to solve this is to add a shadow view below the firstView:

```
UIView *shadowView = [UIView new];
shadowView.frame = firstView.frame;
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadwoView.bounds).CGPath;
[self.view insertSubview:shadowView belowSubview:firstView];
```

Comment: don't forget adding ```shadowRadius``` and ```shadowColor```